# @NgModule, @Injectable @Componenet: Dependency injection and code reuse

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I need to inject a service into a component. All of which is specified in the app.module as shown in the example below.

However my current understanding is that Angular dependency injection on supports programming with classes as opposed to interfaces.

For example: I have two services. DogService and CatService which both  implement AnimalServiceInferface.

```
export interface AnimalServiceInferface {
    makeSound(): String;
}

@Injectable()
export class DogService implements AnimalServiceInferface {
    makeSound(): String {
        return "Woof";
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class CatService implements AnimalServiceInferface {
    makeSound(): String {
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

I then wire up my @NgModule like this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        APP_ROUTES,
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AnimalComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        CatService,
        DogService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

Then, in my component I need to make use of either one of the two services like this.

```
@component()
export class AnimalComponent implements OnInit {

    animalSound: string;

    constructor(animalService: AnimalServiceInferface) {
    }

    onInit() {
        this.animalSound = animalService.makeSound();
    }

}
```

How do I wire this up so that my application can use both AnimalServiceInferface implementations but the implementation used is determined by the situation. For example, this could be determined based on a particular route or a different component configuration.

Many thanks

JT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string or [`OpaqueToken`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) as key

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'AnimalService': useClass: CatService},
    // { provide: 'AnimalService': useClass: DogService}
],
```

```
constructor(@Inject('AnimalService') animalService: AnimalServiceInferface) {
```

If `CatService` or `DogService` is injected depends on where you provide them. If the routed component has a provider registered, then its descendants will get this instance. If not, then DI will look upwards until it finds a provider with a matching key and return the instance of the first provider it finds.

Comment: Thanks. However this does not clearly explain how two seperate routes, using the same component, can use CatService for one route and DogService for the other route. Can this be done?

Comment: You can't control this per route (at least I can't think of a way currently) but you can control this per parent component which might or might not work in your case. Providers are hardcoded with a component (when added to `providers`) and all it's descendants get the instance from this provider unless one of them overrides this in its own `providers` list.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that the real power of this idea is lost. The only work around I can see is to create (empty) components that subclass the main component. uurrghhh....not ideal.